# generate R plot with X-axis only showing data values

Tags: r

[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUo89.png) I'm working on plotting some data.  Currently trying to get a plot to only have natural numbers on the x-axis.  How is that possible?  In the example I'm wondering how I would remove the values 1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would visualize plots like the example using `scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2))`.

```
x = sample(1:2, 1000, replace = T)
y = sample(1:6, 1000, replace = T)
df = data.frame(x, y)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2))
```

This would generate plots like this.

[image: Plot]

Comment: to generalise this, I would replace `breaks = c(1,2)` with `breaks=unique(as.integer(x))`